# How to implement face recognition for login purpose in android app?

Tags: android, face-detection, face-recognition

I want to login the app using face recognition. 
Please provide a solution.

Comment: AFAIK Android does not provide an public API for face recognition till now .. Checkout [This](https://source.android.com/security/biometric)

Comment: https://github.com/Lauszus/FaceRecognitionApp refer  this link

Comment: The above gihub project gives me an error "A problem occurred configuring project ':app'."

Answer (score 0):

You can try Opencv. Just google it and you will get much documentation.

Comment: Thanks for  your solution. I have studied lot of documents but not able to find the satisfactory answer.